# Need to call upon method in different class?

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

Having trouble calling methods from a different class***
Here is my first class. It sets freezing and boiling points for different elements

```
public class FreezingPoint {
private int temperature;


public double getTemperature()
{
    return temperature;
}

public int setTemperature()
{
    return temperature;
}

public boolean isEthylFreezing()
   {
      boolean status;

      if (temperature <= -173.0)
         status = true;
      else
         status = false;

      return status;
   }


public boolean isEthylBoiling()
   {
      boolean status;

      if (temperature >= 172.0)
         status = true;
      else
         status = false;

      return status;
   }


public boolean isOxygenFreezing()
   {
      boolean status;

      if (temperature <= -362.0)
         status = true;
      else
         status = false;

      return status;
   }


public boolean isOxygenBoiling()
   {
      boolean status;

      if (temperature >= -306.0)
         status = true;
      else
         status = false;

      return status;
   }
    public boolean isWaterFreezing()
   {
      boolean status;

      if (temperature <= 32)
         status = true;
      else
         status = false;

      return status;
   }

public boolean isWaterBoiling()
   {
      boolean status;

      if (temperature >= 212)
         status = true;
      else
         status = false;

      return status;
   }
}
```

Now I want a separate class that tests these methods. I want the user to enter the temperature and have the output display a list of substances that will freeze at that temperature and those that boil at that temperature

Having trouble with that part, because I know my getters or setters or methods aren't set up correctly. I know I have to add arguments or constructor but I'm a little rusty its been awhile
So if someone can point me in the right direction in order to display the list of substances that match my criteria^ Heres what I want to build off

```
import java.util.Scanner;



    public class TestFreezingPoint {
         public static void main(String[] args){


         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.printf("Enter a temperature");
         double temperature = in.nextInt();
         boolean repeat = true;
         while (repeat) {
         }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Start by creating an object of type `FreezingPoint`.  I suggest you find a tutorial that explains how to do this, and what you do with the object after that.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create object of FreezingPoint  Class like

```
FreezingPoint obj=new FreezingPoint();
```

then call any method like

```
obj.methodName();
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept which you are implementing is called Inheritance, where one class acquires the properties of another class. The class which gets the property is called "Child Class" and the class which gives it's properties is called "Parent class".

So, here FreezingPoint is Parent & TestFreezingPoint is child. Whenever we want a class to get the properties of another, we give a keyword as "extends".

```
public class TestFreezingPoint extends FreezingPoint {
}
```

Create an object/ instance of the parent class by,

```
FreezingPoint fp = new FreezingPoint();
```

Now, assign the object with methods and pass an argument by,

```
fp.isEthylFreezing(temperature));
```

Finally output as,

```
System.out.println("Ehtyl Freezing? "+ fp.isEthylFreezing());
```

Similarly, use other methods.

Comment: Thanks. how exactly do I assign the methods to the object because what I'm doing isn't working                                                                      System.out.printf("Enter a temperature");
  double temperature = in.nextInt();
  boolean repeat = true;
  
  FreezingPoint fp = new FreezingPoint();
  fp.isEthylFreezing(temperature); 
  System.out.println("Ehtyl Freezing? "+ fp.isEthylFreezing());

Comment: `FreezingPoint fp = new FreezingPoint();
 double temperature;                                                                       
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 temperature= sc.nextDouble();
 System.out.println("Is Water Freezing?" +fp.isWaterFreezing());`